# ClassLoader classcastexception with activemq client

Tags: java, tomcat7, activemq-classic

I have been struggling with this problem for a while now, decided to ask the community, hoping to get some hints/answers.

I am using tomcat 7.0.54 as my J2EE container which has a WAR deployed with dependency on activemq-all.

Along with the above, I'm also placing a jar in the classpath to register a listener programmatically, by implementing the [ServletContainerInitializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) interface. This initializes a simple implementation of an active mq client, JvmMessageProducerImpl (I have activemq-client as a dependency in the pom).

With the above setup, when i try to start tomcat, i get the below exception. It seems that instead of loading the classes independently, the listener which is called when the web application starts, is finding an existing instance of TcpTransportFactory and throwing the ClassCastException. I have read the classloader manual for tomcat multiple times, and my understanding is that each of the war files should have independent Class loaders - but dont completely understand why the exception is being thrown?

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [tcp]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:317)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:330)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:251)
    at com.monitoreverywhere.jvmmon.mq.JvmMessageProducerImpl.setup(JvmMessageProducerImpl.java:66)
    at com.monitoreverywhere.jvmmon.mq.JvmMessageProducerImpl$Runner.run(JvmMessageProducerImpl.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [tcp]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:27)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:181)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:315)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:178)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: The exception occurs because `org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory` is trying to cast a `org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory` to be a `org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory`.  It sounds to me like TransportFactory is finding a TcpTransportFactory, not the other way around.

Comment: that was a typo, made the change thanks

Comment: anyone - i would appreciate if someone who has run into this or similar issue responds.

Comment: Well, incompatible jar files is the obvious guess at a cause.

Comment: Where exactly in your Tomcat installation are you placing the JAR file with the ServletContainerInitializer? It looks as though you may not be able to see the ClassLoader that contains the ActiveMQ library.

Comment: Hi Jake - thanks for your response, I am placing the jar file in the lib directory of the tomcat installation.

Comment: In my case this problem was caused by different class loader - __TransportFactory__ was loaded via __org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi__ class loader, but it returned __TcpTransportFactory__ loaded via __AppClassLoader__. It was caused by incorrect project dependencies - I've both __activemq-osgi__ and __activemq-client__ on my classpath.

Comment: See also this Red Hat issue: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ENTESB-3946?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel